# Custom rating bar displaying only 3 full stars

Tags: javascript, android, xml, android-layout

This is my first time working around with **Rating Bars** in android.
I have a custom rating bar which should look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NShif.png) (I'm sorry, I don't have the reputation needed to put the image on the full display.
All five empty stars look like they should actually, [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az0y7.png), but when I scroll to rate, the full stars become [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeGVG.png).
Following there is the code I've coded until now:

Drawables `custom_ratingbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" />
</layer-list>
```

In my `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="StarRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    2
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_ratingbar</item>
    3
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    4
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
    5
</style>
```

And, finally, in my `fragment_upload_photo.xml`:

```
 <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/StarRatingBar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="83dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1" />
```

Do you know how I can make the rating work as it should? As I told you, this is my first time messing with Rating Bars so all of that XML code previous mentioned is copied from another questions here in `StackOverflow`.

Comment: First opinion try moving the pngs(star_empty/star_full) from "drawable" folder to "drawable-xxxhdpi" folder. This might make too many stars tho, so if this changed the output but it is not the desired one search for all the drawable folders and find the correct one. If not, tell me and i will look more into it.

Comment: Hm, ok, and how do I set it here `<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />` than? What should I use instead of @drawable?

Comment: It remains the same, just move the png into the desired drawable folder

Comment: Well, I moved but it says "cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/star_empty'"

Comment: If you want, try reading here a little about drawable folders. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Comment: Nevermind, I was putting it in mipmap ahaha

Comment: That is good, did it make a difference in the appearance of the rating bar?

Comment: But it didn't help anyways, it stays the same ahah

Comment: Ok, that is bad. I will look into it after i take my dogs for a walk. Working with android native ratingBar is a pain in the a**. If you dont want to wait for me to find out, you can try a third party library like: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6427 It might make your job easier

Comment: Well, I guess I will use that library, I can see that is really a pain ahaha

Comment: Check the resolution if the full star and empty star. They should match. This might be another reason

Comment: Don't leave us hanging, did you do it?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the library you said. Thanks! ^^

Comment: glad to hear it